# Getting Error 'The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD'

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-7, boilerplate

[Error Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o33Lx.png)

**Login Route**

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('index')
    ->breadcrumbs(function (Trail $trail) {
        $trail->push(__('Home'), route('frontend.index'));
    });
```

**Authentication Routes**

```
Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
```

**Problem:**

My project is working fine when I run it locally but when I upload it on the server it shows *Method Not Allowed exception*. I don't know why.
When I used to run URL like **[www.domain.com/billingsystem/](http://www.domain.com/billingsystem/)** it gives the above error but when I run URL like **[www.domain.com/billingsystem/index.php](http://www.domain.com/billingsystem/index.php)** or **[www.domain.com/billingsystem/public](http://www.domain.com/billingsystem/public)** it runs fine on the server.
I am actually not finding the solution for this anyone please help me regarding this.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with your web server configuration. Laravel uses the `index.php` file as the entry point for all its requests. So you have to tell all your sub routes to be passed through this file. The configuration depends on the web server you are using. I'll show you how you can fix it using `nginx` and `apache2`.

#### nginx

Open the configuration file (usually found in `/etc/nginx/sites-avialable/default`) and under the `location` section, edit the line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

to

```
try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php =404;
```

Save the file and restart `nginx` using `sudo service nginx restart`.

#### apache2

For `apache2` you need a properly setup `.htaccess` file under your `/public` directory of your project. By default Laravel ships with one. You just need to tell `apache2` to read that file and respect the rules.

First enable `mod_rewrite` by running:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then go to your `apache2` configuration file located at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and find the section that says `<Directory /var/www/html>` (or the path to your Laravel project `public` folder) and add/edit the line below:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Restart `apache2` using `sudo service apache2 restart`.